# Navigation bar of swt filedialog on windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, openfiledialog

Navigation bar of the open file dialog isn't there in Windows 7 only.

The file dialog is opened from wizard so I get its shell from the wizard.
I get it like.
http://store2.up-00.com/June12/a1V57465.png

but it should be with the navigation bar like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNOWC.png

What I have missed to lose the navigation bar from the file dialog?

Comment: Could you clarify which dialog you are referring to and what you are referring to when you say "navigation bar". Screen captures would probably help.

Comment: Is the first one a real screenshot?

Comment: no I made it with paint, as I was in another place, not on my pc.
So I tried to make the idea clear with some pictures.